# how does regex express for get parentheses part of string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying use regex get parentheses `f` char

```
foo (f123&) ff ccc
```

this is have test express value:

1. `(?i)(?<=\\()\w(?=\\))`. only get parentheses f char, get No match found exception
2. `\\(([a-l])\\)`. same as above.  No match found exception

test code:

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([a-l])\\)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("foo (f123&) ff ccc");
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

I'm have searched not found appropriated answer.

how can get parentheses part of value.

Comment: What do you mean by `get parentheses f char` ? you only want to capture `f` character or whole data in parentheses ?

Comment: @CodeManiac only `f` char

Comment: Your current regex looks for value `(with any character a to i)` you need to change your regex to capture only `f`, `\\(([a-i])[^)]*\\)` here your desired data will be in group 1

Comment: if you're unsure about the position of f, then you need tweak the above regex a bit more. i.e.  this will serve `\\([^a-i]*([a-i])[^)]*\\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex pattern is `\(([a-l])\)`, which won't match because the input string has other content after the single letter and before the closing parenthesis.  I might use `String#replaceAll` here for a one-line option:

```
String input = "foo (f123&) ff ccc";
String output = input.replaceAll("^.*\\(([a-l])[^)]*\\).*$", "$1");
System.out.println("letter is: " + output);
```

This prints:

```
letter is: f
```

If you want an iterative regex solution:

```
String input = "foo (f123&) ff ccc";
String pattern = "\\(([a-l])[^)]*\\)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("MATCH: " + m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: because I'm have many like this string, think of string.replaceAll is slow than regex, so looking for regex express performance will be better :)

Comment: @F___ Check my updated answer for a formal regex solution.  Note that internally `replaceAll` just uses a `Pattern` and `Matcher`, so performance wise, it should be about the same.